# Python would not let me use methods inside the class while the class definition has not been finished

Tags: python, oop, class, methods, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6 as a batch script replacement. It will be started by double-clicking, so all output to stdout will be lost/ignored by the user. So, I decided to add logging, and to make matters simple, I wrote a class for that. The idea is that I can use `Logging.Logger` anywhere in my code, and the logger will be ready to go.

I wish to have no more than 10 old log files in a directory, so I clear out the old ones manually. I have not found a functionality like that through API, plus I am paranoid, and want to log everything, event the fact that there were files with unexpected names inside the log directory.

So, below is my attempt at such class, but I get an error when I try to test (run) it:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/AutomationScripts/build scripts/Deleteme.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Logging:
  File "C:/AutomationScripts/build scripts/Deleteme.py", line 42, in Logging
    __clearOldLogs(dummySetting)
  File "C:/AutomationScripts/build scripts/Deleteme.py", line 38, in __clearOldLogs
    _assert(Logger, 'Logger does not exist yet! Why?')
NameError: global name '_assert' is not defined
>>>
```

Yes, I come from Java/C# background. I am probably not doing things "the Pythonic" way. Please help me do the right thing, and please give a complete answer that would work, instead of simply pointing out holes in my knowledge. I believe I have provided enough of a code sample. Sorry, it would not run without a Settings class, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
# This file has been tested on Python 2.6.*. For Windows only.

import logging          # For actual logging
import tkMessageBox     # To display an error (if logging is unavailable)

class Logging:
    """
    Logging class provides simplified interface to logging
    as well as provides some handy functions.
    """

    # To be set when the logger is properly configured.
    Logger = None

    @staticmethod
    def _assert(condition, message):
        """ Like a regular assert, except that it should be visible to the user. """
        if condition: return
        # Else log and fail
        if Logger:
            Logger.debug(traceback.format_stack())
            Logger.error('Assert failed: ' + message)
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Assert failed: ' + message, traceback.format_stack())            
        assert(condition)

    @staticmethod
    def _removeFromEnd(string, endString):
        _assert(string.endswith(endString),
                "String '{0}' does not end in '{1}'.".format(string, endString))
        return string[:-len(endString)]

    def __clearOldLogs(logSettings):
        """
        We want to clear old (by date) files if we get too many.
        We should call this method only after variable 'Logger' has been created.
        """
        # The following check should not be necessary from outside of
        # Logging class, when it is fully defined
        _assert(Logger, 'Logger does not exist yet! Why?')
        # Do more work here

    def __createLogger(logSettings):
        logFileName = logSettings.LogFileNameFunc()
        #_assert(False, 'Test')
        logName = _removeFromEnd(logFileName, logSettings.FileExtension)
        logFileName = os.path.join(logSettings.BaseDir, logFileName)
        # If someone tried to log something before basicConfig is called,
        # Python creates a default handler that goes to the console and will
        # ignore further basicConfig calls. Remove the handler if there is one.
        root = logging.getLogger()
        if root.handlers:
            for handler in root.handlers:
                root.removeHandler(handler)
        logging.basicConfig(filename = logFileName, name = logName, level = logging.DEBUG, format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        logger = logging.getLogger(logName)
        return logger

    # Settings is a separate class (not dependent on this one).    
    Logger = __createLogger(Settings.LOGGING)
    __clearOldLogs(Settings.LOGGING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This code section will not run when the class is imported.
    # If it is run directly, then we will print debugging info.
    logger = Logging.Logger
    logger.debug('Test debug message.')
    logger.info('Test info message.')
    logger.warning('Test warning message.')
    logger.error('Test error message.')
    logger.critical('Test critical message.')
```

Relevant questions, style suggestions and complete answers are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're getting that exception because you're calling `_assert()` rather than `Logging._assert()`. The error message tells you it's looking for `_assert()` in the module's global namespace rather than in the class namespace; to get it to look in the latter, you have to explicitly specify it.

Of course, in this case, you're trying to do it while the class is still being defined and the name is not available until the class is complete, so it's going to be tough to make that work.

A solution would be to un-indent the following two lines (which I've edited to use the fully qualified name) so that they are outside the class definition; they will be executed right after it.

```
Logger = Logging.__createLogger(Settings.LOGGING)
Logging.__clearOldLogs(Settings.LOGGING)
```

A style suggestion that will help: rather than making a class with a bunch of static methods, consider making them top-level functions in the module. Users of your module (including yourself) will find it easier to get to the functionality they want. There's no reason to use a class just to be a container; the module itself is already just such a container.

A module is basically a single `*.py` file (though you can create modules that have multiple files, this will do for now). When you do an `import`, what you're importing is a module. In your example, `tkMessageBox` and `logging` are both modules. So just make a separate file (making sure its name does not conflict with existing Python module names), save it in the same directory as your main script, and import it in your main script. If you named it `mylogging.py` then you would `import mylogging` and access functions in it as `mylogging.clearOldLogs()` or whatever (similar to how you'd address them now as a class).

"Global" names in Python are not truly global, they're only global *to the module they're defined in.* So a module is a good way to compartmentalize your functionality, especially parts (like logging) that you anticipate reusing in a lot of your future scripts.

Comment: @kindall, when I try to use: `Logging._assert()` inside of the Loggin class, I get the following error: "NameError: name 'Logging' is not defined". I need to find a way to modify my code so that it would run. The single change that you suggested did not do it.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: "it seems weird to expose both classes and functions to the user."?  Why?

Comment: S. Lott, I meant both classes (with functionality) and "lonely" functions. My concern is pollution when I do `from x import *`, even the possibility of such thing.

Comment: @Hamish: I've added more material to my answer to address the isuses you raised. Also, `from x import *` is considered bad style (for various reasons people will be happy to go into if you're interested). One thing you do have to give up in Python is the idea of complete encapsulation; nothing is ever truly private. The leading underscore is merely a warning to callers of your module that a member is implementation-specific and subject to change.

Comment: Thank you, I went back to the tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html which I read before, but details of a module have not registered. The things that you say make sense now.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: "My concern is pollution"?  Pollution of what? I'm not following any of your "concerns".  Please **update** your question with some details on what you are concerned about.  Functions and Classes are both first-class Python constructs and are often in modules.  What problem are you concerned about?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: Then please revise or update the question or delete the comments.  It's confusing to see old stuff here after you've learned something new and important.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line

```
_assert(Logger, 'Logger does not exist yet! Why?')
```

with

```
Logging._assert(Logger, 'Logger does not exist yet! Why?')
```

This is because you define `_assert` as a static method of the class, and static method has to be referred to as `ClassName.methodName` even if you are calling it from a method for an instance of this class.

Comment: When I try `Logging._assert(...`, I get "NameError: name 'Logging' is not defined". I would like a holistic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just needs to be Logging._assert. Python doesn't do namespace resolution the way java does: an unqualified name is either method-local or global. Enclosing scopes like classes won't be searched automatically.

The chapter and verse on how Python deals with names is in section [4.1. Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in the language reference manual. The bit that's relevant here is probably:

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods

Contrast this with names defined in functions, which *are* inherited downwards (into method-local functions and classes):

> If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name

Comment: Could you provide a link to somewhere which explains this in more detail, please?

Answer (score 1):

Some comments.

1. Do not use double underscores unless you are absolutely sure that you have to and why.
2. To access the _assert method, you call it with self. Like so: self._assert(Logger, 'Logger does not exist yet! Why?') In a static method, as in your example, you use the class name: Logger._assert(). Python is very explicit.
3. Classes are only created at the END of the class definition. That's just how it is with Python. But your error is not related to that.
4. I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do:

   ```
   # Settings is a separate class (not dependent on this one).    
   Logger = __createLogger(Settings.LOGGING)
   __clearOldLogs(Settings.LOGGING)
   ```

   But I suspect you should put it in the `__init__` method. I do not immediately see any code that needs access to the class during class construction.
5. `__createLogger` is a strange function. Isn't the class called Logger? Shouldn't that just be the `__init__` of the Logger class?